# Faster way to solve a equation.

Tags: calculus

Solve the equation:
$\sqrt[3]{x-2} + \sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{x+2} = 0$

$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x-2} + \sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{x+2}$

Firstly I check the amount of solutions.

1. Graph of the function starts at the bottom and ends at the top.
2. The derivative is always greater than 0, so the function is always growing.
3. After all of that we know that there is just 1 solution.

Now I try to get the solution:

1. $\sqrt[3]{x-2} + \sqrt[3]{x+2} = -\sqrt[3]{x} $
2. $(\sqrt[3]{x-2} + \sqrt[3]{x+2})^3 = -x $
3. $x-2 + x + 2 + 3\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+2)} + 3\sqrt[3]{(x-2)(x+2)^2} = -x$
4. $3x + 3\sqrt[3]{(x-2)(x+2)}(\sqrt[3]{x-2} + \sqrt[3]{x+2})= 0$
5. $3x + 3\sqrt[3]{(x-2)(x+2)}(-\sqrt[3]{x})= 0$
6. $3(x - \sqrt[3]{x^2-4} * \sqrt[3]{x}) = 0$
7. $\sqrt[3]{x^2} * \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{x^2-4} * \sqrt[3]{x} = 0$
8. $\sqrt[3]{x}(\sqrt[3]{x^2} - \sqrt[3]{x^2-4}) = 0 $

So the solution is $x = 0$.
I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this, without checking the amount of solutions.

Comment: I suppose that you noticed the symmetry.

Comment: In this case the solution $x=0$ is suggested by a simple inspection of the equation. But, in general,I think that  there are no shortcuts for such kind of equation.

Comment: You could just check the integer values from $-5$ to $+5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that for the given function, $f(a)=-f(-a)$ for any value of $a$.

Now put $a=0$.

Thus $f(0)=-f(0)$.

=> $2f(0)=0$

=> $f(0)=0$

=> $x=0$ is a solution.

Also, $f'(x)>0$ for all real numbers $x$.
So, the function is always increasing and thus $x=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: More generally, odd functions have roots at $x=0$ or don't exist at $x=0$.

Comment: Does it ensure that there is just a 1 solution?

Comment: @VereX Yes. Check the edit.