# Find all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+3}+\sqrt[3]{x+4}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as the title says:

> Find all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+3}+\sqrt[3]{x+4}=0$.

I struggle to even start this question.

By inspection, I see that $x$ must be negative. Playing around yields $x=-3$ as a solution, though I do not know how to prove that there are no other solutions.

Upon differentiation, I obtain:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+3}+\sqrt[3]{x+4})&= \frac{1}{3}(\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^{-2}}+\sqrt[3]{(x+3)^{-2}}+\sqrt[3]{({x+4})^{-2}})\\
\end{align}

which is always positive for all real values of $x$, implying that the function defined as $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+2} + \sqrt[3]{x+3} + \sqrt[3]{x+4}$ is strictly increasing.

Is there a better way to solve this equation?

Comment: Well, if you define $z=x+3$ we get $\sqrt[3] {z-1}+\sqrt[3]z + \sqrt [3] {z+1}=0$ which at least makes the $z=0$ solution visible.

Comment: I think you have essentially the best approach, to identify one root and argue the left hand side is a strictly increasing function.  There may be a simpler calculation for the latter, as a sum of strictly increasing functions is again strictly increasing.  But this is just polishing your strategy.

Comment: Related: [Faster way to solve a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2192212/42969)

Comment: You can use the identity $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-bc-ca-ab)$$ to show that $$3(x+3)=3\sqrt[3]{(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)}\,.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y:=x+3$;

$f(y)=(y-1)^{1/3}+y^{1/3}+(y+1)^{1/3}=0$;

By inspection $y=0$ is a solution.

0) $y^{1/3}$ is an odd, increasing function.

1) $y \ge 1$ is ruled out, since $f(y)>0$

2) $y \le -1$ is ruled out, since $f(y)<0$.

Remains $1< y <1$;

3) $f(y)> 0$ for $0<y<1$; since  $-1< (y-1) <0$,  $1<(y+1) <2$:

4) Similarly $f(y) <0$ for $-1<y <0$;

It follows $y=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+3}+\sqrt[3]{x+4}$.

As $g(x)=x^3$ is increasing, the inverse function $h(x)=x^{1/3}$ is also increasing, so $f(x)$, the sum of 3 increasing functions, is also increasing. By the way, $f(x)$ is also continuous.

Inspection shows that $x=-3$ is a  solution. As the function $f(x)$ is both continuous and increasing, $x=-3$ is the only real solution.

Comment: So the only way to do this is by inspection?

Comment: Another way is graphing $f(x)$ and see that $f(x-3)$ is an odd function.

Comment: The term $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is in the quantity of  real numbers only defined if $x\geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt[3]{x+2}=a$ etc.

So, $a+b+c=0$

and  $a^3+c^3=2b^3=2(-a-c)^3=-2(a^3+c^3+3a^2c+3ac^2)$

$$\iff0=a^3+ c^3+2a^2c+2ac^2=(a+c)(a^2-ac+c^2)+2ac(c+a)=(c+a)(a^2+ca+c^2)$$

But $a^2+ca+c^2=0$

$\implies$ either $a=c=0$

or $\dfrac ac=$ imaginary as $\left(\dfrac ac\right)^2+\dfrac ac+1=0$

$\implies a+c=0\implies a^3+c^3=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{x+4}=-\sqrt[3]{x+3}$$

Take Cube in both sides

$$2(x+3)-3\sqrt[3]{(x+2)(x+4)}\sqrt[3]{x+3}=-(x+3)$$

Set $\sqrt[3]{x+3}=y\implies x+3=y^3, (x+2)(x+4)=(y^3-1)(y^3+1)$

$$2y^3-3y\sqrt[3]{y^6-1}=-y^3$$

$$y(y^2-\sqrt[3]{y^6-1})=0$$

If $y\ne0$  $$y^2=\sqrt[3]{y^6-1}$$

Take cube in both sides  $$y^6=y^6-1\iff 0=-1$$ So no finite solutions expect $y=0$

Answer (score 1):

let $t=x+3$ and work with the 'symmetric' form,

$$\sqrt[3]{t-1}+\sqrt[3]{t+1}=-\sqrt[3]{t}\tag{1}$$

Take the cubic power,

$$2t + 3(t^2-1)^{1/3}(\sqrt[3]{t-1}+\sqrt[3]{t+1})=-t$$

Simplify with (1),

$$(t^2-1)t=t^3$$

which leads to the only solution $t=0$, hence $x=-3$.